# react-toolbox Link refreshing entire page

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

I'm using [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com) in one of my projects.

Application structure

```
App
--Navigation
--Content
App
```

App Component

```
<div>
  <HomeNav />
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

HomeNav Component

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
...
<Navigation type="horizontal">
  <Link to="animals">Animals</Link>
  <Link to="plants">Plants</Link>
</Navigation>
```

Note: `Link` in imported from `react-router`

routes

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/animals" />
  <Route path="animals" component={AnimalsPage} />
  <Route path="plants" component={PlantsPage} />
</Route>
```

This is working fine as expected; only the `Content` is refreshed when switching between routes. But when I used [Link](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/link) component from [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com), the entire page is being refreshed.

```
import { Link } from 'react-toolbox/lib/link';
...
<Navigation type="horizontal">
  <Link
    active
    href="animals"
    label="Animals"
  />
  <Link
    href="plants"
    label="Plants"
  />
</Navigation>
```

Is there any way to change this behavior?

In `react-toolbox` documentation, `#` is used in the routes(`#/components/link`). But I have limitations on using `#` in my routes.

Comment: A link is responsible for navigation. If you can't use hash routing, you'll need to either intercept the link click and do an `event.stopPropagation()` or use something other than Link.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

```
import AppBar from 'react-toolbox/lib/app_bar';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

<AppBar title={viewModelProps.headerTitle} leftIcon="menu">
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/login">Login </Link>
</AppBar>
```